# PyQt5 Opening a QMainWindow() class which performs actions on its Ui from another QMainWindow()

Tags: pyqt5

I am teaching myself PyQt5 with and I am pleased with my progress so far, but this has me stumped and I have been working at it for two days. Time to ask for help.

I have a QMainWindow containing a menu entry which is intended to open another QMainWindow, which is contained in a separate source file - I don't want everything in one file, or the single file containing the application I want to write will grow huge.

The second main window class performs substantial modification to its gui through code. I want the second window to be presented with all this code executed, so it is no good just displaying the ui created by Qt5 Designer.

I *almost* have this working. I can click my menu entry in window 1 and window 2 appears with its code executed. So far so good.

My problems are:

- I have to execute myWidget.setVisible(True) twice in succession in
  window 1's code to get the second window to display. If I only
  execute it once, all the code in window 2 executes, as I can see from
  various debug print() statements it contains, but the gui is not
  displayed.
- The second myWidget.setVisible(True) stops execution with the error
  message mywindow.setVisible(True): ***"TypeError: setVisible(self,
  bool): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QWidget'"***
- I can close window 2 through its own menu, but if I try to open it
  again from window 1, window 1 silently disappears.

This is the code fragment in window 1 I am using to open window 2. Clearly it is wrong!

```
def open_frmMainWindowMenuTest(self): #This is window 2
    print("Setting myWidget = QMainWindow()")
    myWindow = QMainWindow()
    print("Setting myWidget = mywindow()")
    myWidget = mywindow() #This is the class of window 2
    print("myWidget.setVisible(True)")
    myWidget.setVisible(True)
    print("mywindow.setVisible(True)")
    mywindow.setVisible(True)
    print("Flying")
```

The final *print("Flying")* is not executed.

The attached screenshot shows what I want to happen without throwing an error. Window 'SofTRAK Maintenance' is opening window 'Table Test Harness'.

Any help would be appreciated.

***BY THE WAY: This is NOT a duplicate question.*** As far as I can find, all other solutions involve opening the second window's Ui WITHOUT running any relevant code in the second QMainWindow. I have Googled 'till my fingers bled.   "8-)

[image: SofTRAK Maintenance has opened Table Test Harness]

Comment: OK - I will attempt to trim everything down and post the code. I am sure the issue is with the code fragment I have posted, but will certainly do as you ask.   "8-)

Comment: In the code that shows I do not see any problem, there are still redundancies that you point out that it does not make sense. Also I have heard many times to indicate to the OP that the error is in the code that shows but in the end it is discovered that the error is in the code that adds to the end, so to discard it in SO we demand a [mcve]

Comment: Another thing that seems strange to me is that you indicate that it is not a duplicate without anyone having indicated it. :-)

Comment: I just thought I would jump the gun, in case someone thought "We have had thousands of questions about calling a window, so mark this as duplicate". Sorry if I was out of line.

Comment: It is only marked as a duplicate if the question has been resolved before (and it is not bad to mark it as a duplicate because it indicates that there is already a solution that will save you time, rejoice), and for that you must at least be certain of where the problem is , but its code does not lead to that, currently falls in the topic: *why is not this code working?*

Comment: Thank you for the correction to my code. So simple! Your corrected code works perfectly, of course. I really appreciate your help.   "8-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

frmMainWindowCallTest.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *

from ui_frmTestMainWindowCall import Ui_frmTestMainWindowCall  # importing our generated file
from frmMainWindowCalledTest  import mywindow 


class thiswindow(QMainWindow, Ui_frmTestMainWindowCall):

    def __init__(self, **kwds):
        super(thiswindow, self).__init__(**kwds)

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.actionTest_Call.triggered.connect(self.open_frmMainWindowMenuTest)

    def open_frmMainWindowMenuTest(self):
        print("Setting myWidget = mywindow()")
        self.myWidget = mywindow()                    # <---  self.
#        print("myWidget.setVisible(True)")
#        self.myWidget.setVisible(True)
#        print("mywindow.setVisible(True)")
#        mywindow.setVisible(True)
#        print("Flying")

        self.myWidget.show()                          # +++


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
application = thiswindow()
application.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! It works fine the first time, but not all my code is running the second time - however, I can now open and close the secongd window when I want to, so my question is answered. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: As an aside, I have worked out why my code did not seem to run fully the second time around. I have two dictionaries declared before "class mywindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):". I was popping values from the lists returned as items from the second dictionary. When I called the window for a second time from the first window, these lists were empty. I assumed (bad idea) that everything would be refreshed each time the window was opened from another window, but this does not seem to be the case. I presume this has something to do with global vs local variables in the application space?